# Point set topology exercise: prove that the following subset of the complex plane is open.

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $f:{\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow{\mathbb{C}}$ is a continuous function. I want to prove that for any real positive constant $M$, the set $$G=\{z\in{\mathbb{C}}:|f(z)|<M\}$$ is open. My argument is as follows: Since $f$ is continuous as is $z\mapsto{|z|}$, the mapping $z\mapsto{|f(z)|}$ must be a continuous mapping from ${\mathbb{C}}\rightarrow{[0,\infty]}$, and since $[0,M)$ is an open set in the subspace topology that $[0,\infty)$ inherits from the real line, $G=f^{-1}([0,M))$ must be open in $\mathbb{C}$. This argument (if correct) seems to provide a unified proof that any open disc (centered anywhere), or sets of the form (say) $$G=\{z\in{\mathbb{C}}:|z^{2}+z|<M\},$$ or $$G=\{z\in{\mathbb{C}}:|z^{3}+z+1|<M\}$$ are open. These statements seem to be hard to establish directly i.e. by proving that every point is an interior point explicitly (as one would for the open unit disc say). [I feel a little uncomfortable about invoking the subspace topology! But cannot see why it would be wrong].

Comment: Seems more like, if $g : \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{R}^+$ is the map $z \mapsto |z|$, then $G = f^{-1}g^{-1}([0,M))$

Comment: Indeed, this precisely what I meant to say.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/). Consider also to upvote that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine. The "hardness" of establishing that the sets at the end of your post are open is hidden in the proof of the continuity of the polynomials. Proving that all polynomials are continuous is not that difficult, but it requires some work.

To avoid the subspace topology, you can just note that
$$
G = f^{-1}((-M,M)).
$$

Comment: Your response emboldens me to suggest that a similar argument can be used to prove that many subsets of the complex plane are closed-the inverse images of closed sets under continuous maps remain closed. Your way of avoiding the subspace topology makes me feel better!